# Why does an error occur with this code?

Tags: java

I'm learning about inheritance in my AP Computer Science class and was confused by this question:

Find the output produced by the following code:

```
public class A {
    private int xx;

    public A() { 
        xx = 1;
    }

    public A(int x) { 
        xx = x;
    }

    public void addX(int x) {
        xx += x;
    }

    public void multX(int x) {
        xx *= x;
    }

    public int getXX() {
        return xx;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ""+xx;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private int yy;

    public B(int y) { 
        yy = y;
    }

    public void addY(int y){
        yy += y;
    }

    public void multY(int y) {
        yy *= y;
    }

    public int getYY() {
        return yy;
    }    

    public void addBtoA(){
        addX(yy);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ""+yy;
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
A a = new A(14);
B b = new B(33);
b.addBtoA();
System.out.println( a.getYY() );
```

I do not understand why this results in an error. Please help!

Comment: What "error"? How does this differ from what was expected? And *why*? Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

The class `A` does not have a method `getYY`

This should be

```
 System.out.println( b.getYY() );
```

Answer (score 1):

`B` extends `A`, so `B` inherits all the methods (unless overridden) from `A`, so `B` objects can access `A` methods, but the reverse is not true. `getYY()` is a method defined for `B` objects, so you will get an error when trying yo access it with `A` objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Error With a.getYY() Because how you can call public method of class B on the reference of class A**

> As I got its kind of single inheritance. Java allows sub class to know all the public properties of super class. So you can call the all the public methods and attributes of A in B(example b.addX(10)). But Vice versa is not allowed here, you are not able to call the methods in B from reference of A because reference of class A in your case a is not having any knowledge about class B.
>
> If then also you want to call it then refer InstanceOf operator
>   [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator)